# Print Json Nested Array in Array all elements

Tags: arrays, json, angular, nested

[JSON DATA Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJQkd.png)
I have Json file nested data the data is inside the array in array and some array have inside 2 array and some have 4  and some folders don't have ant array . I want print all array data if inside 2,3,4 and nested 2 or 4 .

I print the 3 array data in angular using the for loop inside the loop .i use 3 for loop and 3 times data print

```
 <ul *ngFor="let bird of parts_">
     <li>{{bird.name}}</li>
     <li [ngStyle]="{'color': bird.type == 'folder' ? 'red' : 'green'}"> 
        {{bird.type}}</li>
     <ul *ngFor="let item of bird.items">
       <li>{{item.name}}</li>
       <li >
       <ul *ngFor="let item1 of item.items">
         <li>{{item1.name}}</li>

         <ul *ngFor="let item2 of item1.items">
           <li>{{item2.name}}</li>
         </ul>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>

</ul>
```

[3 Time Loop Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL3ls.png) 
i want output is that program to print the data inside array if have 3,4,7 folder . i don't want use loop again and again . So i want print all json data array on file in once all dynamically.

Comment: then you should create a component which takes array as input and use that component recursively inside it's template

Comment: map your array inside your compoent thn print it in template

Comment: Can you send sample code for component array

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create **component that accepts folder through** `@Input` field and this component will **display current folder name** and **if folder has child folders** it will iterate through them and **use self (same component) to display every single folder** (by passing every folder to the component via `@Input` field).

With such recursion you will not need to repeat your loops manually.
Hope that helps.